# Declare the size of vector in HashMap

Tags: java, vector, hashmap

I have the following bit of code:

```
public HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Vector<Vector<String>>> recipes;
```

The outer `Vector`should be of size 3 and the inner `Vector`'s at each indice can be of infinite size.

How would I do this, and is it even possible?

Some background:

I need something that is of size 3, because each indice corresponds to a different meal of the day. 0 is breakfast, which will store a list of food items for breakfast, 1 is lunch, and 2 is dinner. How can I accomplish this setup.

Comment: Please don't use `Vector`. Program as if it doesn't exist. (You cannot set a fixed size for instances of that type. If you only want three elements in it, only add three elements.)

Comment: I updated my post with some background on what I want to do.

Comment: Instead of using a `List`, create a type with three fields, one for each meal of the day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ArrayList` rather than `Vector`.

Also, aim to refer to interfaces rather than concrete implementations:

```
Map<GregorianCalendar, List<List<String>>>
```

You cannot fix the size of a `Vector` or an `ArrayList`. If your outer lists always have size 3 it may be better to use a custom class instead.

```
class MealData {

    List<String> breakfastItems;
    List<String> lunchItems;
    List<String> dinnerItems;
}
```

Then you could use a `Map<GregorianCalendar, MealData>` instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll do this instead.

Comment: No problem. It's much better this way. `mealData.getBreakfastItems()` is much more descriptive than `mealData.get(0);`.

Comment: Very true. Thank you. Would I need a constructor to create all of the lists, or will they automatically be created when the HashMap is?

Comment: No when the `HashMap` is created, you have an empty `HashMap` and no lists at all.. You'll need to flesh the class out (make the fields private, add a constructor and getters etc etc). When you want to add to the `HashMap` do `map.put(???, new MealData(......));`.

Answer (score 0):

At this point you are just defining the content type of your classes (generics), you can define the size of the vector once you assign it.
So for example

```
public HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Vector<Vector<String>>> recipes;
recipes = new HashMap<GregorianCalendar, Vector<Vector<String>>>();
Vector<Vector<String>> myVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>(5);
Vector<String> innerVector = new Vector<String>(3);
```

Then you will have to assign the values:

```
innerVector.add("test");
myVector.add(innerVector);
recipes.put(myVector)
```

Using interfaces is more a design choice than mandatory, you can use the concrete clases or the interfaces e.g. if you are planning to change the implementation